# Linker error when passing data from Swift to Objective C

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, ios10.3, fxforms

I am using FXForm Library and want to get data from my Swift file in Objective C file function.

**Demo Project** [Link](http://dropbox.com/s/mqytb5p7ia285pb/test.zip?dl=0)

Swift Code Implimnetation:

```
let fontName  = "HelveticaNeue"
let fontSizeLarge:CGFloat = 14.0
var hiddenElementFromFormIndex = [Int]()

//fx form variables
@objc class FXFormVariables : NSObject {
    public override init() {}
    class func FXFontName() -> String { return fontName }
    class func FXFontSize() -> CGFloat { return fontSizeLarge }
    class func FXHiddenCell() -> NSArray { return hiddenElementFromFormIndex as NSArray }
}
```

In Objective C file, I am getting error when we write below like:

```
NSArray *hideArray = [FXFormVariables FXHiddenCell];
```

I created the bridge header file correctly and Target Membership is checked in the Objective C file.

Error I am getting:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$__TtCC13Social_Engine11AppDelegate15FXFormVariables", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FXForms.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Architectures and Valid Architectures are:

```
armv7 and armv64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use Swift class inside Objective-C file you need to import *Xcode-generated header file* in your Objective-C file.

```
#import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h"
```

I created a **Test** project with the same name.

**Swift File:**
    //
    //  FXFormVariables.swift
    //  Test
    //
    //  Created by Puneet Sharma2 on 12/07/17.
    //  Copyright © 2017 com.puneet.sh2525. All rights reserved.
    //

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

let fontName  = "HelveticaNeue"
let fontSizeLarge:CGFloat = 14.0
var hiddenElementFromFormIndex = [Int]()

//fx form variables
@objc class FXFormVariables : NSObject {
    public override init() {}
    class func FXFontName() -> String { return fontName }
    class func FXFontSize() -> CGFloat { return fontSizeLarge }
    class func FXHiddenCell() -> NSArray { return hiddenElementFromFormIndex as NSArray }
}
```

**Objective-C File**

```
#import "ABC.h"
#import "Test-Swift.h"

@implementation ABC


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSArray *hideArray = [FXFormVariables FXHiddenCell];
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But this is still not working. I have made the demo project and uploaded on dropbox. Can you please download and check. Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mqytb5p7ia285pb/test.zip?dl=0

Comment: You have written FXFormVariables as an inner class in AppDelegate. Just put it as a separate class inside the same file.

Comment: Yes, I have written FXFormVariables inside AppDelegate class.

Comment: Thank you Puneet, it work like charm, you made my day.

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal: Apparently, it looks like tere is some bug in Swift while importing Switf inner class in Objective-C. https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2267 I would recommend you either edit the same question to include this info and wait for answer or dont make FXFormVariables as inner(nested) class.

Comment: I need small from you, can you please provide your email id?

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal: Accpeted your linked in request. You can message me there.

Comment: Thanks you puneet.

Answer (score 0):

Literally I spent hours trying to figure out why this was happening with one of my swift files that i was importing into my Objc codebase, and the real reason was due to the use of a nested class.

Such as:

```
@objc public class MyClass {
 @objc public class SecondClass {}
}
```

And if I tried using SecondClass in my objective-c code, I would the Apple Mach O-Link errors of death. So the solution was to de-nest the class you want to use.

```
@objc public class MyClass {}
@objc public class SecondClass {}
```